Why do rockets need such powerful engines?
The starship catch between the two arms has been all over the internet. And it made me wonder, why do rockets need such powerful engines?
Although I am very comfortable with math, I barely know any physics. My knowledge doesn’t go beyond average high school mechanics, and even that I studied it years ago.
So, my reasoning was this: if we apply a force greater than the force of gravity acting on the rocket (mass x 9.8 N/kg), say 10 newtons more than this force, the rocket should accelerate upwards. Since the force is always there, according to Newton’s second law, the acceleration is there, so it should fly. If we keep on applying this small force and the acceleration is constant, it should reach space eventually, even if it’s slow, meaning without reaching the escape velocity.
This is clearly wrong, but I can't understand why!
Could you please provide an intuitive answer? Don’t hesitate to use math if necessary.

Well, I got just the same idea some time ago. It is a very good idea, but we just don't have the engines ready for that. You could go to the moon without wasting insane amount of fuel, heat-shields, huge rockets, great speed... but you can't do it with lame rockets like we have now.

Rockets are big because as well as their payload they have to carry their own propellant and oxidiser. You can (in theory) make a much smaller orbital vehicle if you give it an (insane) amount of kinetic energy at launch - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch. Or you can use a smaller rocket  if you launch it from a high-flying aircraft - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-launch-to-orbit.

@Mithoron, In a very real sense, the "distance" between any two points in a space mission can be expressed in terms of a number called "delta-V" ("delta vee"). The units are meters per second. E.g., from the surface of the Earth to low orbit around the Moon, it's roughly 12,700 m/s. To land on the Moon, you need a bit more. To get home again, more still. If you know the mass of the payload, and the total delta-V for a space mission, then that's most of what governs the size of the rocket you're going to need. If you already knew all of that, then what kind of propulsion were you imagining...

...could go to the Moon using less fuel than the systems that we use today would need? OTOH, if "delta-V" is new to you, then you might want to learn more. Google is your friend.

@SolomonSlow This is more of a q. for space exploration.se, but there are many options. For example space elevator could get you to orbit without any rocket at all. Just a bit more force than Earth exerts - like OP says.

As far as rockets are concerned, for example powerful variant of VASIMR, or any other which could generate constant thrust during whole journey.

The engines are just powerful enough, but higher power is more efficient.
Let's assume the thrust is only just enough to lift the rocket. In that case, the rocket will burn prodigious amounts of fuel to get nowhere. If the thrust is slightly higher, it will start accelerating slowly, while still burning massive amounts of fuel.
This will get the rocket going. Then, as it burns fuel it gets lighter, so it will accelerate faster. You may have noticed that rockets usually start moving slowly, but rapidly increase their acceleration, even though they have not increased engine power. That's because the rocket gets lighter as the engines burn fuel.
In the case of Saturn V, the most powerful rocket yet, the total mass at take-off was almost 3,000 tons. The 5 S-1C engines delivered a total thrust of around 3,500 tons. In other words, just enough to start going. Fully fuelled, the first stage had a mass of 2,300 tons, of which 2,150 tons was fuel. It burnt through that in 150 seconds, so that every second Saturn V got about 14 tons lighter, and accelerated correspondingly faster.
As slow take-offs waste a lot of fuel, we want rockets to accelerate as fast as possible - within the limits of engine power and what the rocket/payload can endure. Military rockets can take off very quickly because they have been "hardened". Human payloads and spacecraft require gentler take offs.
In other words, it's a trade-off between the desire to use less fuel, and the limitations of the rocket/cargo.

However, why must rockets reach escape velocity? If an object goes upwards at a constant speed of 1m/s, shouldn't it eventually get too far from earth that earth's gravity no longer effects it?

@Denis See https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/

@Denis,"Why must rockets reach escape velocity?" Most of them don't. An object moving at or above Earth's escape velocity will leave the Earth, and never come back. It doesn't need a motor at that point. It's own inertia will carry it away from Earth forever. Most of the payloads ever launched merely orbit the Earth. Orbital velocity is less than escape velocity. The only spacecraft that ever reach Earth's escape velocity are the ones that visit other Solar system planets and asteroids. Only five have ever reached the Sun's escape velocity.

Once in orbit, even minimal thrust (e.g. an ion thruster or a solar sail) will eventually let the spacecraft achieve escape velocity. However, as long as the spacecraft wants to fall back down (i.e. below orbital velocity, or going in the wrong direction for orbit) higher thrust is cheaper.

"eventually get too far from earth that earth's gravity no longer effects it" Gravity stretches to infinity, but it influence weakens with the inverse square of the distance.
